# Angular2 how to pass @output variable from one component to another component

Tags: angular

I have a sidebar component which has a variable user

```
export class SidebarComponent {
user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));


  constructor(private service: AuthService) {
    this.user = this.service.profileUpdated$.subscribe(profile => {
      this.user = profile;

    });

  }
```

How can I pass this `user` variable to another component? I am fairly new to Angular2

Comment: It sounds weirs that you need this at all.

Comment: I need to access this user value in another component to make a service call

Comment: Sounds even weirder. Can you provide a Plunker that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: I think you should inject the `AuthService` in the component where you need the value and subscribe there instead of subscribing in one component and passing the value.

Comment: Makes sense .. but wouldn't I be writing redundant code ? Just wondering if there is  a better way to do it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by duplicate code. If you want a value from an observable in a service, just inject the service and subscribe. That's much easier to understand than copying values around in several steps. The service should take care that multiple subscribers don't cause multiple requests to to a server if any and that multiple subscribers are properly supported (for example by using the `share` operator)

Comment: Thanks I'll follow this